# Using multiple Roots with a Durandal application

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

**Problem:**

My application does not start; it just goes into an infinite loop.

**Code:**

My app.start:

```
app.start().then(function() {
            //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
            //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
            viewLocator.useConvention();

            //configure routing
            router.useConvention();

            router.mapNav('home');
            router.mapNav('intro');
            router.mapNav('error');
            router.mapRoute('set/:id', 'viewmodels/set', 'Set');
            router.mapRoute('folder/:id', 'viewmodels/folder', 'Folder');
            router.mapRoute('api', 'viewmodels/api', 'API Reference');


            app.adaptToDevice();

            app.setRoot('viewmodels/intro');
            //logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
            /*
            router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
                //debugger;
                //router.navigateTo('#/error');
            };
            */
        });
```

I set the root to intro, which contains a simple viewmodel that has a login function:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/dataservice'], function (app, router, dataservice) {
var introViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.router = router;

    self.logIn = function () {
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
    };

    self.activate = function () {
        return router.activate('intro');
    };
```

The goal here is to re-set the root of the application if the user is logged in.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you have main.js -> intro.js -> intro.js
should be main.js -> intro.js -> home.js.  Are you using shell.js?

Comment: I have shell.js, but it should only get set as the root when I click login.  Am I router.activating incorrectly in intro.js (the lower code)?  I thought that was just binding the router to the view.  I'm doing that in both intro.js and shell.js (but router.activate('home') in shell.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Rob over on the Google Groups, I just plucked the router from my intro page and ran it in my shell.js, activating the router only once.  This seems to tighten things up a bit and the app is working now:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/RdGpwIm1oOU

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rob's answer at the Google Groups page, here are some specifics that worked for me that may help others:

- In main.js app.start().then():  set root to be your login page.
- After login, configure your router and add routes to it.  (Adding
  routes *must* come before router activation.)  This is an opportunity
  to retrieve only those routes to which the user has access as part of
  the login process.
- Finally, set app root to be the shell, which then activates the
  router with the default route you specify.  Currently, I modify the
  activate function in router to take an additional parameter of a
  start url--that way, I can bypass the default page if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, the first part (setroot to login), I did this but the login page wasn´t loaded, no errors was showed also.

In main I simply put app.setRoot('viewmodels/login', 'entrance');

In login I simply have an activate function:

```
function activate() {
    return true;
}
```

Is it correct?